# TexStudio in Mac OSX El Capitan Error: package not found

Tags: packages

Why if I want to use `eskd` or `eskdx` packages does TeXStudio show me an error message: "not found `eskd.sty`"?

I installed MacTeX and TeXStudio with default settings, and moved project from PC. But when I added `\usepackage{eskd}`, TeXStudio showed me the error message?

My project compiled without errors before I added this string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @cfr: In the TeX Catalogue on Line, they're both mentioned as included?!

Comment: @Bernard So it does. However, there is no `eskdx.sty` in either TeX Live or CTAN as far as I can tell. Not sure about `eskd.sty`.

Comment: There is an `eskd.cls`. Have you tried `\documentclass{eskd}`?

Comment: Welcome! I deleted my initial Welcome! because it was followed by an erroneous conjecture, as noted by @Bernard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, TeX terminology uses 'package' in 2 senses.

1. A package is a collection of one or more files distributed together. These are packages in the CTAN / TeX Live sense. In this sense, a package may include several files with various names for various purposes. The package may or may not be designed for or usable with the LaTeX format.
2. A package is a LaTeX style which is designed to provide a particular group of functions or to change particular aspects of a document's appearance. A package is loaded with `\usepackage{<package name>}` which reads the corresponding `<package name>.sty`.

The problem in this case is that `eskd` and `eskdx` are packages in the first sense but not the second. So neither `\usepackage{eskd}` nor `\usepackage{eskdx}` will work.

`eskd` provides a *class* rather than a LaTeX package. To use it, you would start your document with

```
\documentclass{eskd}
```

`eskdx` provides a number of different LaTeX packages. If you need to use these, I suggest taking a look at the manual to see how they should be loaded and used.

Comment: I've taken a look at their ‘test’ folder on CTAN, ant it seems the general class should be `eskdtext`. If the O.P. reads Russian (which I don't), he/she should take a look at the documentation.

Comment: @Bernard You mean for `eskdx`? `eskd` definitely provides `eskd.cls`.

Comment: @Bernard `eskdx` also provides `eskdgraph.cls` and `eskdtab.cls`.

Comment: Yes, for eskdx (the other one is not in MiKTeX). For the other classes, that's why I wrote ‘ the *general* class’. For me it's a weird  organisation, and it would be better to take a look (at least) at the documentation.

Comment: Ok, in documentation for eskd, esdk - is a class. Used: document[]{eskd}. Thx for answers!

Comment: @Bernard The other classes appear to be for documentation, maybe? Judging by the comments. As you say, the documentation probably explains things.